# The python program is giving no result

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to code a card game in python using OOP.
the user should select either red( hearts and diamonds)
or black( clubs and spades)
the user then goes on with the game.

here is the code:

```
import random

class Card:
    def __init__(self, name, suit):
        self.name = name
        self.suit = suit

    def print_card(self):
        print(self.name + ' of ' + self.suit)

    def show(self):
        print('{} of {}'.format(self.suit, self.name))

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        for s in ['Hearts', 'diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades']:
            for v in range(1, 14):
                self.cards.append(Card(s, v))
    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def show(self):
        for c in self.cards:
            c.show()


class Game:
    def __init__(self, player, score):
        self.player = player
        self.score = score
        self.cards = []
        self.hand = []

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def drawCard(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

    def draw(self, deck):
        self.hand.append(deck.drawCard())
        return self

    def showHand(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.show()

    def reset(self):
        pass
print('Welcome message')
user = input("Please enter your name: ")
print('While you start your score is 1000')
team = input((' RED or BLACK  \n Your team : '))
while True:
    if team == 'red':
        print('Great, You have chosen Team Red, hearts and diamonds will fetch you points, clubs and sp')
        print("")
        playGame = input(('Press ENTER to play'))
        print('Game starts')
        shuffleCard = input(('Press ENTER to shuffle and Pick your card'))

        deck = Deck()
        deck.shuffle()

        print('That was a good mix')

        showCard = input(('Press ENTER to reveal your card'))
        user = Game(user, 1000)
        user.showHand --> here i am expecting the final card to show up but its not happening
```

the terminal gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yoshithkotla/PycharmProjects/pythonFinalProject001/main.py", line 71, in <module>
    player = player()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Details of the problem : Using the OOP topics and programs we examined in our Lecture Notes 8 and 9 develop a Python
program to implement a card game.
 You select the card game.
o You  can  invent  your  own  simple  card  game;  just  provide  the  instructions  for  your  card
game as comments in your Python program.
 In our Lecture Notes 9, we will be developing OOP Python code for the fundamentals of a card
game. Use this code in your implementation of your card game. Add additional OOP code for your
specific card game.

Comment: `player` is a string object.

Comment: Why did you edit the code so as to remove the code that was causing the error? After the edit, your question makes no sense since it contains an error message referring to code no longer there.

Answer (score 1):

Changes made:-
`player=player() -> player=game()`

**Code:-**

```
class game:
    def __init__(self, player, score):
        self.player = player
        self.score = score

    def start_game(self, player, score, team):
        self.score = score
        self.player = player
        self.team = team

print("Welcome")
player = input("Please enter your name: ")
print('While you start your score is 1000')
team = input((' RED or BLACK  \n Your team : '))
while team == 'red':
    print('Great, You have chosen Team Red, hearts and diamonds will fetch you points, clubs and sp')
    print("")
    playGame = input(('Press ENTER to play'))
    print('game starts')
    shuffleCard = input(('Press ENTER to shuffle and Pick your card'))
    deck = Deck()
    deck.shuffle()
    print(' that was a good mix')
    showCard = input(('Press ENTER to reveal your card'))
    player = game()
    player.draw(deck)
    player.showHand
    break
```

**Output:-**

```
Welcome
Please enter your name: Yash
While you start your score is 1000
 RED or BLACK  
 Your team : red
 Great, You have chosen Team Red, hearts and diamonds will fetch you points, clubs and sp

Press ENTER to play
```

**Updated query:-**

I think you should go with the process to learn all the conditions for the game than start your code.. for reference you should **follow this ->** [click here](https://thecleverprogrammer.com/2020/10/04/card-game-with-python/) to know all the conditions for the game and then try to code..!

Comment: I made the changes
this is the error i get now,

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yoshithkotla/PycharmProjects/pythonFinalProject001/main.py", line 73, in <module>
    player.draw(deck)
AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'draw'

Comment: where you initialised your class `deck` in your code... The error reason is you have no `Deck`  class... in the line `deck=Deck()`

Comment: I think you have the `Deck class`  just you have not share it. I think the error.. you have not defined a function `draw`. In line `player.draw()` your `game class` not contains `function draw` .. also in the next line you are doing `player.showHand` i don't see any function name `showhand` in your `class game`

Comment: i made the changes, but now the code stops at 'Press ENTER to reveal your card
'

Comment: here is the code in the following comments because i cant paste entire code in one comment

Comment: class Game:
    
    def __init__(self, player, score):
        self.player = player
        self.score = score
        self.hand = []
    def start_game(self, player, score, team):
        self.score = score
        self.player = player
        self.team = team
    def showHand(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.show()
    def draw(self, deck):
        self.hand.append(deck.drawCard())
        return self

Comment: print("Welcome")
user = input("Please enter your name: ")
variable = Game(user, 1000)
print('While you start your score is 1000')
team = input((' RED or BLACK  \n Your team : '))

Comment: while True:
    if team == 'red':
        print('Great, You have chosen Team Red, hearts and diamonds will fetch you points, clubs and sp')
        print("")
        playGame = input(('Press ENTER to play'))
        print('Game starts')
        shuffleCard = input(('Press ENTER to shuffle and Pick your card'))
        deck = Deck()
        deck.shuffle()
        print('That was a good mix')
        showCard = input(('Press ENTER to reveal your card'))
        user = Game(user, 1000)
        user.draw(deck)
        user.showHand

Comment: you can update your code in question also.. please update the question so that it will be  more readable

Comment: when you updated your question.. please let me know..

Comment: Now your code runs to the line `press enter to shuffle and pick your card` than the error came. the error is because you have no class `Deck` which i mentioned earlier. so write the `class Deck` and what you wants from this class ..

Comment: just wanted to give a feedback that please start writing your code after all the conditions you have processed in your mind. also please see the updated query for the reference i have added the link

Answer (score 0):

In the line `player = player()` you are trying to call a function named 'player' by adding brackets. Player is not a function but a string variable where you store the entered name of a player, so you cannot call it.
Try to erase the brackets or delete line completely (since you've already assigned the variable in line `player = input("Please enter your name: ")`).